# How to I provide positive feedback to user who comments/responds to my post

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, accepted-answer

In the following post, [How do I terminate a SwingWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348668/how-do-i-terminate-a-swingworker), there is a user named "matt" who I would like to provide positive feedback, as he has been very helpful. How do I do that?

Comment: You could ask if they want to post an answer because then you can accept their answer (that is the green check mark that is next to an answer), assuming their answer is helpful to you. Once you reached 15 reputation you can also upvote their answer.

Comment: @rene there is no up button next to there comment, just a flag for serious problems or moderator attention.

Comment: sorry, comment vote up also comes at  15 rep. I missed that: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: @rene Ok. Thanks. Another question: should I comment that their post was helpful? I recall that maybe I'm not supposed to. That is what the up buttons are for. I want to be careful not to turn this into a chat room, but keep it to questions and answers.

Comment: What we normally do is use comments to ask for clarification about a post or point out issues. it is not a means to chat a bit between visitors of the post. You could ask (once) if a user is willing to promote their comment to an answer. If they don't or don't respond then you best move on and eventually even clean-up those comments as they add nothing to the post.

Comment: Related help article: [What I should do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Rubén not really related, their question is not answered, at least not by a proper answer but by some comments at best.

Comment: So, in this case responds ≠ anwers

Answer (score 2):

Wait a couple of days for matt to make up their mind. Do not accept the answer if somebody else tries to run with it, hunting for reputation. (Disconcertingly, we even have had users deliberately changing their display name to do exactly that!) If matt does not respond, you can always write up the answer yourself. If you don't want the credit of possible upvotes, you can mark it a Community Wiki.

And, if possible, write more than just copying the exact comment. I recently had a user doing that with one of my suggestions – adding it helped them resolve their issue but not telling how. It made for a pretty crappy answer – my comment was merely a direction to investigate – and alas the OP did not respond to an invitation to explain how it had helped.

Comment: I generally agree with this, but if matt really doesn't want to answer or abandons the thread and someone else winds up posting a very similar answer that happens to communicate the same solution (or heck, a better solution, if it exists--I'm not familiar with the problem domain), I don't see a problem with accepting it. It'd be pretty obviously low-quality if someone just copied and pasted matt's comments into an answer and matt's inaction in moving a comment to an answer doesn't need to be accommodated indefinitely. OP self-answering with information gained in comments seems like a good bet.